# Não consigo receber os dados na minha api

Tags: php, android

Tenho o seguinte método para enviar um objeto a minha api:

```
public void btnCadastrar(View view) throws JSONException, IOException {

    final EditText edtNome = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome));
    final EditText edtSobrenome = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSobrenome));
    EditText edtCelular = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCelular));
    EditText edtCep = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCep));
    EditText edtLogradouro = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLogradouro));
    EditText edtBairro = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtBairro));
    EditText edtLocalidade = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCidade));
    EditText edtUF = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUF));

    String nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
    String sobrenome = edtSobrenome.getText().toString();
    String celular = edtCelular.getText().toString();
    String cep = edtCep.getText().toString();
    String logradouro = edtLogradouro.getText().toString();
    String bairro = edtBairro.getText().toString();
    String cidade = edtLocalidade.getText().toString();
    String uf = edtUF.getText().toString();

    JSONObject dadosJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    dadosJsonObject.put("nome", edtNome.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("sobrenome", edtSobrenome.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("celular", edtCelular.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("cep", edtCep.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("logradouro", edtLogradouro.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("bairro", edtBairro.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("cidade", edtLocalidade.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.put("uf", edtUF.getText().toString());
    dadosJsonObject.toString();

    JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PATCH,
            "http://reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/usuarios.php", dadosJsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Dados retornados: "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );

        mVolleyRequest.add(json);

    }

}
```

E essa é minha API:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($dadosJsonObject);

var_dump($data);
?>
```

Quando clico no botão para enviar o objeto para a api, uma mensagem aparece na tela do emulador dizendo que a aplicação parou e não consigo achar o erro.

Comment: Poderia adiconar o log do erro ? fica máis fácil para ajudar!

Comment: Você sabe debugar o código?

Comment: Ai que tá, não tem log de erro.. Pelo menos não aparece nenhum erro. Como posso colocar esse log e onde?

Comment: Como e onde posso colocar o log @ThiagoLuizDomacoki

Comment: Achei o erro:
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.gustavo.domanda.CadastroActivity.btnCadastrar"